# Need Computer A to talk to Computer B and Computer C but Computer B and C should not talk to each other

Tags: networking

I have Computer A that needs to talk to Computer B and Computer C.  But I don't want Computer B to talk to Computer C.  Can this be accomplished using Private VLANs or will I need to create ACLs or Firewall Rules to do it?

Comment: Firewall rules/ACLs or subnetting/routing rules are generally easier to deal with than VLANs (and VLANs often still rely on firewall or routing rules). It can technically be done if Computer A is assigned/trunked to both vlans.

Answer (score 0):

VLANs might work, depending on your router.

Firewall rules will surely work, but you will need to give all the
computers static IP addresses for this to work. With dynamic IPs,
the computers are not guaranteed of keeping the same IP that was
used in the firewall rule.
Your router might have a DHCP option to always attribute the same IP
to the same computers.

The weakness of firewall rules as a solution is that if the users
of computers B & C, if they have Administrator logins,
could remove these rules.